# How can an event listener point to a different object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, addeventlistener

I am trying to do the TicTacToe assignment from the Odin Project.

here is my JavaScript

```
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
console.log(boxes);
console.log('working');

const board = [
];

for (let i = 0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
    const objectBox = {position: i+1,
                        ownership: 'none'}

    board.push(objectBox);
    boxes[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(this);
    });

}
```

and here is my HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://css.gg/css?=|bot|boy" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
    <div id="board">
        <div class="box no-ownership"></div>
        <div class="box no-ownership"></div>
        <div class="box no-ownership"></div>
        <div class="box no-ownership"></div>
        <div class="box no-ownership"></div>
        <div class="box no-ownership"></div>
        <div class="box no-ownership"></div>
        <div class="box no-ownership"></div>
        <div class="box no-ownership"></div>

    </div>
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I have an array that contains objects with informations like ownership of the square. Obviously the eventlistener points to the div so i'm not able to access the object. What I would like is for example to have access to `objectBox[0]` when I click on the first square

I couldn't really find any informations online.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `i` in the event handler (`console.log(i)`), store the index on the element (`data-*`), find the index of the clicked `<div>` (`.indexOf()`, `.findIndex()`), ... -> What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: Thanks, I knew I had to keep track of their positions but I didn't know how as obviously i couldn't access i once the loop had ran and I didn't know about data-*

Comment: By the time your loop finishes, the value of `i` would be the number of `.box` elements + 1. Which doesn't exist. You need to either define a closure inside your for loop or declare `i` with `let1 keyword

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but you can simply use `objectBox` inside your event handler, which gives you access to your custom object. It is declared with `const` thus each iteration has it's own `objectBox`. Alternatively you could also use `board[i]` to get access to the object. This does require a `let` declaration of `i` (which you have). `let` creates a separate `i` for each iteration whereas `var` uses a single `i` for all iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the objectBox variable in the event handler, as it is defined inside the same scope.

```
const objectBox = {position: i+1,
                    ownership: 'none'}

board.push(objectBox);
boxes[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(this);
    console.log(objectBox.ownership);
});
```

EDIT2: This is generally bad practice, it would be better to map the HTML element and data object to cutom variable, or: "A cleaner way would be to use data- properties to store the index of the dataObject you want to associate with this element." @AdityaParab

Except from that, I believe you can assign the objectBox variable to the queried element by itself, e.g.:
EDIT: commented

```
for (let i = 0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
    //declares variable (allocates memmory and returns "pointer")
    const objectBox = {position: i+1,
                    ownership: 'none'}

    board.push(objectBox);
    boxes[i].dataObject = objectBox;
    boxes[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(this);
        //holds the reference to objectBox regardeless of i value
        //the loop creates 9 event handlers and each stores reference to the object created in relevant loop run
        console.log(this.dataObject);
    });
}
```

EDIT: How it doesnt work

if you tried to create the objectBox variables and then reference them inside onclick method in two separate loops...

```
for (let i = 0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
    //declares variable (allocates memmory and returns "pointer")
    const objectBox = {position: i+1, ownership: 'none'}
}

for (let i = 0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        //this would assign the LAST objectBox to ALL event handlers, as the objectBox variable would be 9 times overwritten in the previous loop
        console.log(this.dataObject);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works. But I don't understand 100%. When the page load 9 eventlisteners are created , one for each div, but the functions in the eventlistener is ran only when i click and so once the loop as ran no ? So how do I not get the last object only ? i should be equal 9 at the end of the loop no ?

Comment: @altho _"i should be equal 9 at the end of the loop"_ - Yes. But because you've declared `i` with `let` there's one `i` per iteration and not one for the whole loop.

Comment: You're a bit confused, but you have the spirit! :) I dont think that the let keyword changes anything here, VAR keyword declaration would have worked as well. The difference here is in something else, the objectBox is declared inside the FOR loop scope as well as the event handler - the event handler itself holds pointer reference to the objectBox variable and this pointer is different for all 9 "different" event handlers.
If you looped again on lines under the for loop and tried to reference the objectBox, you would always get the last object.
EDT:Ill show some example in the answer itself.

Comment: One should avoid adding extra properties (custom properties) to the HTMLElements.. A cleaner way would be to use `data-` properties to store the index of the dataObject you want to associate with this element

Comment: Thanks a lot, really. What ressources could I read to become more familiar with this type of thinking ? It's not the first time i'm confused with large numbers of eventlisteners in a loop.

Comment: in short waht you should do is `boxes[i].dataset.index =  i + 1;`And in your click handler `const dataObject = boxes[this.dataset.index]`

Comment: @AdityaParab is correct about the extra properties to HTMLElement.